# Setting a value to a input inside of var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm curios is it possible to access and modify data inside of javascript var, so far i tried it with pure javascript as well as with jquery. So both versions are fine for me.

```
var data = {
    'name': 'Jhone',
    'category': 'Human',
    'type': 'good one',
},
    form = `<input type='text' name='name' id='name'>
            <input type='text' name='category' id='category'>
            <input type='text' name='type' id='type'>`;
```

JQuery version (not working)

```
$.each(data, function( key, value ) {

    if ($.type(value) === 'string' && value !== '')
        $(form).find('#'+key).val(value)
});
```

JavaScript version (not working) (sorry don't know how to make foreach in pure js but the problem is with accessing element)

```
$.each(data, function( key, value ) {

    if ($.type(value) === 'string' && value !== '')
        form.getElementById(key).value = value ;
});
```

The main point is that i want to create js forms dynamically and avoid setting data like :

```
var form = `<input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='`+ value +`'>`;
```

Comment: That variable is just that -- a variable. You have to actually put it into the DOM

Comment: After declaring your variable: `form.value = 'Jhone';`. `getElementByX` will return an empty list when trying to find an element that is not in the DOM.

Comment: @KévinBibollet String's do not support the `value` property

Comment: @Taplar - Oh right, I commented too fast. So he will have to use `document.createElement` when declaring `form`. And also setting the element's attributes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ES6 Template Literals(Strings)](https://medium.com/@_bengarrison/javascript-shorts-1-es6-template-literals-strings-14e1b91585cb) and do something like this:

```js
var id = "This_is_a_test_id"
var form = `<input type='text' name='name' id='${id}'>`;
console.log(form)
```

Comment: It doesnt have internet explorer support. You can use this, just with  id='" + name + "'

Comment: @Comirdc That's a largely solved problem: transpile with polyfills. (Mind you if that's not practical, that is a valid point.)

Comment: I dont think he mentioned that hes using it, but you are right about solved problem.

Comment: This actually works :) ty, and i like that its not giving any errors or warnings if element is empty. But still its not like something i wanted to achieve. I'll update my code a bit to be closer to what i'm doing.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's a string, you would have to parse it first to be able to use operations like setting the value.

```js
var form = `<input type='text' name='name' id='name'>`

form = $(form).attr('value', 'myvalue').prop('outerHTML');

console.log(form);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A vanilla javascript version using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`Element#setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```js
const input = document.createElement('input'),
  attributes = {type: 'text', name: 'name', value: 'Jhone'};

for (let attr in attributes) input.setAttribute(attr, attributes[attr]);

document.body.appendChild(input);
```

Or if you want to write your input with HTML:

```js
// First, append your <input>'s HTML into your DOM.
const inputHtml = '<input type="text" name="name">';
document.body.innerHTML += inputHtml;

// Then, get it and set its [value] attribute.
document.querySelector('input').value = 'Johne';
```

Answer (score 0):

**Revision after OP edit**

```js
// Create form element
const form = document.createElement('form'),
  data = {
    'name': 'Jhone',
    'category': 'Human',
    'type': 'good one',
  };

for (let prop in data) {
  // Create DOM element
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  // Set input attributes
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input.setAttribute('name', prop);
  input.setAttribute('id', prop);
  input.setAttribute('value', data[prop]);
  // Append input to form
  form.appendChild(input);
}
// Append form to document (for snippet purposes)
document.getElementById('form').appendChild(form)
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="form"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Before OP edit**

Yes, but you're doing it wrong.

First of all, `` var form = `<input type='text' name='name' id='name'>`; `` is a string, not a DOM element. You'd need to create a DOM element to manipulate it in the way you intended. Something like:

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'text';
input.name = 'name';
input.id = 'name';
form.appendChild(input);
```

You can now look for elements inside of `form`, but not using `getElementById`. Use `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` for this.

```
var nameInput = form.querySelector('#name');
```

You can now manipulate this DOM Element the way you intended

```
nameInput.value = 'Head over to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model to level up your DOM manipulation skills'
```